# Disproving the mean-value theorem of calculus to complex functions?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives, soft-question

I'm defining a function $f(z) = z^3 + 1$, and I will let two points 
$$z_1 = \frac{-1+i\sqrt3}{2}\quad\text{and}\quad z_2 =\frac{-1-i\sqrt3}{2}.$$

I am trying to show that there is no point $w$ on the line segment from $z_1$ to $z_2$ such that $$f(z_2) - f(z_1) = f'(w)(z_2-z_1).$$

I'm not too sure how I can take a point w and make a function out of it, and even find its derivative. Any help? I'm not too sure where i would even start.

We know from calculus that a point on the line segment would have the form $$-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}(1-2t),$$ where $0 \le t \le 1$.

Comment: I might have a proof for this considering a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$, maybe it could be useful? You want it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(z_1)=f(z_2)=2$, but $f'(z)=3z^2=0$ only when $z=0$, and $z=0$ does not lie in the segment
$$
\left[\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right].
$$ 
Note that
$$
\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}=\cos(2\pi/3)+i\sin(2\pi/3),
$$
and hence
$$
\left(\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{\!3}=\big(\cos(2\pi/3)+i\sin(2\pi/3)\big)^3=
\cos(3\cdot 2\pi/3)+i\sin(3\cdot 2\pi/3)=1.
$$

Comment: Why would you take the derivative of the function f(z)? I don't understand that bit.

Comment: Did you read what you yourself wrote in your question, @Matthew? What do you mean why Yiorgos took the derivative?!

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit disconnected here (I apologize) but I guess what's really tripping me up is how you get from a point w and make it into a function then find the derivative.

Comment: @DonAntonio One more thing that's not quite clear to me. If a function is easily broken into real and imaginary parts, can I take their modulus and treat that as Z itself?
How did you know right away that f(z1) and f(z2) = 0?

Comment: @Matthew ,"To take a point and make into a function..." ? Why do you think anything even close to this is going on here? The MVT in real analysis says that the difference between the values on two *different* point of a nice function equals its derivative in some intermediate value times $\;\pm$ the distance between the points: $$\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=f'(c)\;,\;\;c\in (x,y)$$

Comment: No, you can't take the modulus of $\;z\;$ as $\;z\;$ itself. In general these two are very different things. And I (and others) knew at once that $\;f(z_i)=0\;$ since both given points are roots of $\;-1\;$ of order three, something you should have studied before getting into (complex) analysis

Comment: How did you know so quickly that((−1+i3√)/2)^3+1, as well as it's counterpart, were 0 so fast?

Comment: Just a note, $z_1$ and $z_2$ are third roots of unity, so $f(z_1) = f(z_2) = 2$, not $= 0$.

Comment: @Matthew: See correction. $$\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}=\cos (2\pi/3)+i\sin(2\pi/3),$$ and hence $$\left(\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{\!3}=1.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Wouldn't that mean you could take |z| instead of z_i to get sqrt((-.5)^2 + (sqrt(3)/2)^2) = sqrt(1/4 + 3/4) = 1, so then 1^3 + 1 = 2 ..................?

Comment: @Matthew For these particular points you have indeed $z_1^3 = \lvert z_1\rvert^3$. But in general, that would be terribly wrong. What is the idea behind taking $\lvert z\rvert$ as the argument of $f$ anyway?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis How can you conclude that? I'm sorry I'm a bit confused. My class had a very unstable teacher the first 6 weeks. We're fixed now, but we're missing a lot of crucial information.

Comment: @Matthew: Could you be more specific? Which part you want me to explain?

Comment: Your last comment where you used Euler's rule then concluded that the function^3 = 1.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis

Comment: @Matthew: See updated version.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Oh okay, so that's just De-Moivre's formula - Excellent!

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis I feel really stupid but then how did you conclude that that final expression is equal to 1?

Comment: @Matthew: $\cos 2\pi=1$ and $\sin 2\pi=0$.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Whoa! I completely should have caught that. I wanted to let you know that you've been a big help. Thank you.